# I want to order items returned from an object based on the property key value and then assign a ranking to each item in the interface (1,2,3...etc)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, key

Newb here with a basic question. Here is my object:

```
{TestOne: 12, TestTwo: 6, TestThree: 4, TestFour: 2}
```

I've looped through it using a for-in loop and grabbed the properties and displayed it in my UI like so:

- TestOne: 12
- TestTwo: 6
- TestThree: 4
- TestFour: 2

I need to be able to display this by giving each item a numerical ranking (1,2,3,4...etc) and then displaying them by that ranking (corresponding to their actual order). In other words, what my users need to see on the screen is:

- TestOne: 4
- TestTwo: 3
- TestThree: 2
- TestFour: 1

Not 12,6,4,2, etc. This is all new to me but I've been trying to figure out the best way to implement this and have not found anything that I understand to this point.

Here is my code. I feel like this should be easy but it is super frustrating!

```
 var rank = "";
    var title = objArrayTwo[i].Title;
    var summary ={};
    summary = groupBy(objArrayTwo);

    for (var prop in summary) {
        if (summary.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if(title == `${prop}`){
                rank = `${summary[prop]}`;
            }   

        }
    }

    function groupBy(items){
        var result= {};
        var sum;                    
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        sum = result[item.RequestName] || 0;
        result[item.RequestName] = sum + parseInt(item.Rank);                     
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj = {TestOne: 12, TestTwo: 6, TestThree: 4, TestFour: 2};

// sort the array
var arr = Object.entries(obj);
arr.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);

// enumerate the array the index would be the rank
var arr_with_rank = arr.map((data, index) => [data[0], index+1]).reverse()

arr_with_rank.forEach(x => console.log(x[0] + ": " + x[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

ES5 solution

```js
var resultDataObject = {
  TestOne: 12,
  TestTwo: 6,
  TestThree: 4,
  TestFour: 2
};

var descendingSort = function(a, b) {
  return resultDataObject[b] - resultDataObject[a]
};
var sortedResultKeys = Object.keys(resultDataObject).sort(descendingSort);

var resultWithRank = sortedResultKeys.map(function(k, i) {
  return {
    title: k,
    score: resultDataObject[k],
    rank: i + 1
  };
})
console.log(resultWithRank)
```